# Clarify the duplicate error message in the review queue

Tags: discussion, support, review, duplicate-questions

It's a bit of an unusual situation I got myself into while reviewing the close queue. This doesn't seem like a bug - rather some sort of system to prevent marking 2 questions as duplicate of each other.

[image]

But, how would I know which one should be flagged as a duplicate?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3297500) is the item from the queue that generated the error while trying to mark as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817399/subscript-out-of-range-error-in-this-excel-vba-script).

But, it seems like there are 4 questions that are very very close to each other (*from the same user*)

- [How do i resolve the file mismatch in this vba script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799320/how-do-i-resolve-the-file-mismatch-in-this-vba-script)
- [Updated the vba code and still it gives me a subscript out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818319/updated-the-vba-code-and-still-it-gives-me-a-subscript-out-of-range-error)
- [Subscript out of range error in this excel vba script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817399/subscript-out-of-range-error-in-this-excel-vba-script)
- [This Piece of code still does not update excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815472/this-piece-of-code-still-does-not-update-excel)

I am not going to lie; I am really confused here and not sure what to do to properly close the right questions and leave the other open.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: per my recollection, this message is displayed _after_ dupe closure has been completed, ie "dupe-relation" is already established in a direction opposite to one presented to you. I typically check that by opening suggested dupe in a separate browser tab and making sure it's closed the way I suspect

Comment: Just see which one is not voted to be closed as duplicate already, and mark all the rest as a dupes of it. In case of already circled votes, bringing it to meta seems the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we have four questions that are essentially about the same piece of code:

**[A]** [How do i resolve the file mismatch in this vba script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799320/how-do-i-resolve-the-file-mismatch-in-this-vba-script)

**[B]** [Updated the vba code and still it gives me a subscript out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818319/updated-the-vba-code-and-still-it-gives-me-a-subscript-out-of-range-error)

**[C]** [Subscript out of range error in this excel vba script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817399/subscript-out-of-range-error-in-this-excel-vba-script)

**[D]** [This Piece of code still does not update excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815472/this-piece-of-code-still-does-not-update-excel)

The system has detected that you were about to cast the deciding vote that would close **[B]** as a duplicate of **[C]**, yet **[C]** was already closed as a duplicate of **[B]**.

From what I can tell, the best candidate to remain open is **[B]**. So we just need to close **[A]** and **[D]** as duplicates of **[B]**.

Comment: Yes I agree. The only concern I still have it's that while reviewing I wouldn't know that there are 4 duplicate questions so I would need to spend about 10 minutes just to sort out one question going through the OPs questions and figuring this whole thing out. It would be nice if there was filter on asking new questions that would prevent people from posting exact or ~95% similar code to their previous question. And thanks for your answer @Duncan

Comment: @mehow Yes, sometimes a simple close vote review triggers a complicated ten minute detective effort! You can search meta to see if someone has suggested something similiar (I'm sure they have) and see the feedback on that. Or post a feature request if you can't find anything.